# Converting data-structure in Perl

Tags: data-structures, perl

A function produces this hash of arrays:

```
'KEYNAME1' => ARRAY(0x1edeeb0)
   0  'val11'
   1  'val12'
   2  'val13'
'KEYNAME2' => ARRAY(0x1efacb8)
   0  'val21'
   1  'val22'
   2  'val23'
```

Another function requires an array of hashes containing arrays:

```
0  HASH(0x1f6df98)
   'KEYNAME1' => ARRAY(0x1f776b0)
      0  'val11'
      1  'val12'
      2  'val13'
1  HASH(0x1f6dfe0)
   'KEYNAME2' => ARRAY(0x1f6df80)
      0  'val21'
      1  'val22'
      2  'val23'
```

[This code](http://pastebin.com/Fg5UutQm) converts the first to the second, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This segment of code is redundant because `@{$hash{$feld}}` already contains exactly what you produce in `@array`.

```
my @array;
foreach my $wert (@ {$hash{$feld}}) {
    print "wert $wert";
    push @array, $wert;
}
```

Here is a simpler solution.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = (
    KEYNAME1 => [qw( val11 val12 val12 )],
    KEYNAME2 => [qw( val21 val22 val23 )],
);
print Dumper \%hash;

my @array;
while ( my ($key, $val) = each %hash ) {
    push @array, {$key => $val};
}
print Dumper \@array;
```

A map could be used instead of the while loop, but I think the loop is easier to read.

```
my @array = map { {$_ => $hash{$_}} } keys %hash;
```